# Не работает vue либо что-то в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

Хочу установить стандартный webpack-simple vue проект.
далаю по инструкции

```
$ npm install -g vue    
$ npm install -g vue-cli  
$ vue init webpack-simple my-project
```

на этом этапе предлагает ввести имя проекта и описание и выпадает, так ничего и не создав.
В чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 0):

Баг оказался в новой версии ноды.
Поставил старую и всё заработало.
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/can-no-longer-create-any-new-vue-projects-with-vue-cli/35229/2